# Get elevation for multiple lon and lat using Earth Engine in Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, elevation

I'm new at Google Earth Engine and I need it for one simple task for research purposes,
I have a list of nodes like this

```
node1:[lon,lat]
node2:[lon,lat]
node3:[lon,lat]
```

I would like to get the elevation data for each long and lat
the output should be like this

```
dataframe
lon,lat,elev
lon,lat,elev
lon,lat,elev
```

Can anyone give a good answer for a similar problem ( I try to search for it and I didn't find any solution)

PS: I'm not interested in the slope of polygon I'm interested in specific points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the Python API since you used the `python` tag.

I leave you an example code:

```
DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003")

node1 = [-72, -42]
node2 = [-73, -42]
node3 = [-72, -43]
node4 = [-73, -43]

nodes = [node1, node2, node3, node4]

# make points from nodes
points = [ee.Geometry.Point(coord) for coord in nodes]

# make features from points (name by list order)
feats = [ee.Feature(p, {'name': 'node{}'.format(i)}) for i, p in enumerate(points)]

# make a featurecollection from points
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(feats)

# extract points from DEM
reducer = ee.Reducer.first()
data = DEM.reduceRegions(fc, reducer.setOutputs(['elevation']), 30)

# see data
for feat in data.getInfo()['features']:
    print(feat['properties'])

# export as CSV
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(data, 'pointsDataExtract', 'FOLDER', 'nameOfCSV')
task.start()
```

Comment: man you are a hero can you recommend some resources to learn to integrate python and EE rather that the official earth engine site tutorials i would like to learn more

Comment: Qiusheng Wu has made some you might find useful, look in his github https://github.com/giswqs